# When carrying out my unit tests, how can I execute custom code if at least one of my unit tests fails?

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, node.js-tape

In a test file, I've added several unit tests using the [Tape test harness](https://github.com/substack/tape). What I'd like to do now is ensure that, if at least one of my unit tests fails ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8hYpZ.jpg)), some custom JS code is executed.  How would I approach that?

In this case, the custom code I'd like to carry out will play a sound (which I plan to do using the [sound-play](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sound-play) Node package.

If it matters, I'm running the unit tests in VSCode, and the Tape output is currently printed to VSCode's output panel.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out that Tape has an [onFailure method](https://github.com/substack/tape#testonfailurefn), which fires a callback whenever at least one test fails.  This was exactly what I needed.